# How to hyphenate "Churchill"?

Tags: hyphenation

How should "Churchill" be hyphenated when it breaks across two lines?

- Chu-rchill,
- Chur-chill,
- Churc-hill, or
- Church-ill?

Comment: It has been shown that it is impossible to break Churchill.

Comment: Related *What are the rules for splitting words at the end of a line?* http://english.stackexchange.com/q/385/14666

Comment: *Chu-rchill* or *Churc-hill* would be the wrong pronunciation (if pronounceable at all).

Comment: @TimLymington Yes. Neither *Chu-rchill* nor *Churc-hill* but *Church•ill* is possible probably assuming *Church* + *hill* with the aspirate at the front of *hill* being 'not pronounced' ('pronounced' in the sense of 'emphasized.')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its actually ........  **"Chur-chill"**

[Hey check this out](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/churchill)

Comment: Maybe you're right. But the reference points to pronunciation, not hyphenation in spelling.

Answer (score 1):

(c) Purdue OWL on [Hyphen Use](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/576/01/)
5.

> Use a hyphen to divide words at the end of a line if necessary, and make the break only between syllables:
>   pref-er-ence
>   sell-ing
>   in-di-vid-u-al-ist

The TFD entry for **[Churchill](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/churchill)** lists more than one possibility for the syllabification.
Chur·chill (?AHD)
Church•ill (?Random House)