# Rules for hyphens in words and phrases

Tags: phrases

What are general rules for when hyphens are used in words such as "bad-ass" or "well-deserved". Could someone explain what kinds of words/phrases those are?

Comment: Actually, most dictionaries list *badass* without a hyphen, and it has been spelled that way for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are [hyphenated compound words](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/hyphen#hyphens_in_compound_words) or hyphenated phrasal verbs

> Hyphens in compound words
>
> Hyphens are used in many compound words to show that the component words have a combined meaning (e.g. a pick-me-up, mother-in-law, good-hearted) or that there is a relationship between the words that make up the compound: for example, rock-forming minerals are minerals that form rocks. But you don’t need to use them in every type of compound word.

Comment: Is there a difference between what kind of compound words they are?

Comment: Please see the link - it describes verbs, nouns, adjectives and phrasal verbs

Comment: Your link explains what I need to know. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

when you can't finish a word in the same line, you put a - after the first part of the word and continue the rest of the word in next line

Comment: This is not what is asked - you are referring to [hyphenation](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385/what-are-the-rules-for-splitting-words-at-the-end-of-a-line)