# Hypenating in the middle of a person's name

Tags: hyphenation

The editor or a Club bulletin split's a person's name if it comes at the end of the line in an article.  I do not believe this is grammatically correct, but I cannot find a ruling in writing to present to the editor.

Comment: I think it's perfectly fine as long as you break it according to standard phonological rules for hyphenation. Which means (1) you need to know how to pronounce the name and (2) you need to know [the rules.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/74583/5754) Since most people don't know the rules, the standard advice is: don't do it, so as to avoid abominable line-breaks like *Siob-han* or *Cap-one*.

Comment: This has nothing to do with *grammar*, but with the typographical conventions of the publication, and as such there is no "right answer."

Comment: Any chance you can edit the title for spelling "hyp_H_enating"? :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a topic on typographical conventions, not English itself.

Comment: @jimm101 While there may be stylistic reasons not to break a name, the OP is asking if it is grammatically correct. It's undeniable that English orthography is on topic, including punctuation rules such as hyphenation.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/615072/2085).

Answer (score 4):

[englishplus.com](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000129.htm) has some interesting insight on the rules, such as they are, for dividing words at the end of a line with a hyphen. They basically say don't do it, but if you have to here are seven rules to follow:

- Divide the word between syllables. This means, of course, that one-syllable words are never divided.
- The hyphen goes at the end of the first line.
- Prefixes and suffixes make natural divisions.
- There should be at least two letters plus the hyphen on the first line and three letters on the second.
- Do not divide proper nouns or proper adjectives.
- Divide hyphenated word using the hyphen already in the word.
- Do not divide a word at the end of a line if the parts of the word will be on two separate pages. This is hard for the reader to follow.

The one relevant to your quandary would be point 5, as names are proper nouns. Obviously this isn't an official source, but I find it hard to argue with the advice given.