# Why is the word "mimic" divided into syllables as mim-ic and not mi-mic

Tags: syllables

I would like to know why, when dividing the word mimic into its syllables, is it divided as "mim" and "ic" and not "mi" and "mic". Is there any rule to this?

Comment: Because that's the way it's pronounced.

Comment: if its any help, i say both

Comment: "separated", not "seperated". Also, that's not the correct word. "divided" is better, but I think you were looking for "hyphenated".

Comment: It's neither, the middle m is shared by both. Where you put the hyphen is just a convention.

Comment: Useful reading includes http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315838 and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385

Answer (score 1):

One rule of English pronunciation which is actually correct sometimes is that the vowel in an "open" syllable is "long" while the vowel in a "closed" syllable is "short".

Thus, if "mimic" is divided as "mi-mic" then the first syllable is "open" (has a trailing vowel) and so the "i" would be "long" (and "mi" would be pronounced "my").  If the word is divided as "mim-ic", though, the "i" is "short", and the pronunciation of the first syllable would be "mem" (as in "memory").

Like all such rules, there are many, many exceptions, but this one often works for "sounding out" an unfamiliar word (if you can first figure out the syllable splits).