# How to hyphenate (divide at the end of a line) the word "configurable"?

Tags: hyphenation

Just as the heading says: How do we hyphenate (in the sense of: divide at the end of a line) the word `configurable`?

- I was quite surprised that Merriam-Webster doesn't know that word.
- The Oxford English Dictionary neither shows hyphenation nor syllabication.
- Microsoft Word 2010 offers `con-fig-u-ra-ble`, which I believe to be incorrect since I have read somewhere that `a-` at the end of a line, followed by `ble` at the begin of the next line would mislead the reader in most cases, and that `able` therefore usually should be kept together.
- hunspell (which drives most open-source projects like OpenOffice, LibreOffice, Firefox, Thunderbird and the like) says `con+fig+urable`, which I believe to be correct, but not complete.

My personal feeling is that it could be `con+fig+ur+able`, but as a native German speaker who never has been in a country where English is spoken as primary language, I am lost at this point.

Could somebody please help me out?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/615072/2085).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyphenation for breaking words across lines in English is quite arcane — [see this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385/what-are-the-rules-for-splitting-words-at-the-end-of-a-line).

In AmE, it should be

> con-fig-ur-able.

We hyphenate *configure* as [*con-fig-ure*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/configure), as dictionaries can tell you. The *ur* should not be broken up because it's an r-influenced vowel, and American English doesn't usually break them up. And the ending should be hyphenated as in *pleasurable* ([*plea-sur-able*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pleasurable)), whose ending is pronounced the same.

British English hyphenates r-influenced vowels different from American English, and I don't know what the rules are. But I don't think anybody is going to object if you use the AmE hyphenation for this word.

Comment: Thank you very much, +1 and accepted. In fact, I am more after American English than after British English. So AmE does not keep `able` together in most cases? Could you please give a short explanation regarding the difference between `configurable` and `pleasurable`with respect to the `able` (`-ur-a-ble` in one case and `-ur-able` in the other)?

Comment: Actually, that was a typo. I meant to write *-able*. However, this depends on the dictionary. [American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=pleasurable)  breaks these words *-a-ble.* But [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pleasurable) keeps *-able* together (which would be my recommendation). This discrepancy is why my answer was inconsistent.