# Where can I make a line break in “predesign”?

Tags: orthography, syllables

At which point can I make a line break in *predesign*?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about the English language.

Comment: Oh I am sorry I always thought it is about the English language. What is it about?

Comment: The EL&U community is about English. However, your question seems to be about typesetting. It might help for you to elaborate on your question to clarify. You can use the [edit] link to do that.

Comment: I hope this might help.  It would be best and logical to choose to place the hyphen after "pre-" in order to preserve the uninterrupted meaning of the original unsplit word.  By contrast, hyphenating after "Prede-", and then placing "sign" on the next line, would confuse the meaning of the original word.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question, because it is about **punctuation**.

Comment: I agree—punctuation is quite relevant to English.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/615072/2085).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule is that words can be hyphenated at syllable boundaries. Many good dictionaries mark syllable boundaries to show you where words can be hyphenated <sup>[1](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/hyphenanddash/hyphen)</sup>.

Still, according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/predesign), ***predesign*** has only one  division point at which a hyphen may be put at the end of a line:

> pre·design

Which seems rather odd, given that *[**design**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/design)* itself can be split as:

> de·sign

Also [***redesign***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redesign):

> re·de·sign

---

See a more general discussion [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385/what-are-the-rules-for-splitting-words-at-the-end-of-a-line).

Comment: Merriam-Webster does not say it only has two syllables. If you look at the definition of words in that dictionary, the centered dot is used to delineate end-of-line word breaks *not* syllables: As it [explains](https://www.merriam-webster.com/help/explanatory-notes/dict-entries): "The centered dots within entry words indicate division points at which a hyphen may be put at the end of a line of print or writing."

Comment: @JasonBassford I believe the general rule is that words can be hyphenated at syllable boundaries.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But your statement that Merriam-Webster is indicating two syllables is false. It's not. It's indicating the end-of-line break.

Comment: @JasonBassford What would you call them, then (the two parts)?

Comment: You said in your answer that "according to Merriam-Webster, predesign has two syllables." That is not true. The dot used by the dictionary is only indicating an end-of-line division. In this case, the line break is between the first and second syllables (the word has three). Look at [athe•ism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/atheism). It has *four* syllables, but the centered dot shows the line break between the second and third syllables.

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes, you've said that already. I asked what should I call the two parts instead.

Comment: The word has three syllables. The part on the left of the dot, one syllable, is what goes at the end of the first line of text; the part on the right of the dot, two syllables, is what goes at the start of the second line of text. If you like, you can call each side a word division.

Comment: @JasonBassford Well, I am not sure the distinction matters in the given context, but I have edited my answer to satisfy the pedants.

Comment: I think the reason why Merriam Webster says it only has one hyphen-spot is because connecting pre - design is intuitive, as is de - sign. But seeing prede -sign is a bit jarring as one may interpret it as "prede-sign". Since "sign" is an actual word, one could be left asking what a prede-sign is. (Although de-sign, still, is easy to decipher when broken at the end of a line.)