# Where should I break the word "illness" into syllables and why?

Tags: syllables

In *The Complete Guide to Spelling* by John J Fulford, he writes "With double consonants, the division is between the two consonants unless they are at the end of the word. Never split a blend or digraph."

He then gives the following examples.

- suc/cess
- ill/ness
- ac/cid/ent
- suck/ing

Is it just me or did he immediately break this rule will "illness"? The way it's broken up makes logical sense but why?

Comment: He did. That's because there's another rule that conflicts with this one: break words at morpheme boundaries.. And here *ill* and *ness* constitute morphemes. See [this answer.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385/what-are-the-rules-for-splitting-words-at-the-end-of-a-line/74583#74583)

Comment: That is to say, English spelling does not allow consistent syllabification of spelled words. So just do what you think looks best and don't worry. That's what everybody else does, after all.

Comment: When he says 'unless they are at the end of the word', he means 'unless the first syllable is a complete word' (like _ill_ and _suck_).

Comment: Thank you guys that helps a lot