# If you must split the word anonymous at the end of a line, where should the hyphen go?

Tags: hyphenation

If you must split the word anonymous at the end of a text line, where should the hyphen go? How would you split the word?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the rules for splitting words at the end of a line?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385/what-are-the-rules-for-splitting-words-at-the-end-of-a-line) The dictionaries say *anon-ymous* or *anony-mous*. Take your pick. And next time, look the answer up in a dictionary.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/615072/2085).