# What are the syllables in "photography"?

Tags: pronunciation, syllables

How come every website I could find is saying that syllables in "photography" are pho-tog-ra-phy? Shouldn't it be pho-**to-gra**-phy? Where did that "tog" come from?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking about the word or its spelling?

Comment: Are you asking about syllables (pronunciation) or hyphenation points (writing)?

Comment: I really don't think hyphenation is anything to do with what the OP is asking about. I had an answer all ready to go right as this was closed.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've voted to reopen.  I am eager to read your answer.

Comment: @phoog - I hope it's saved it in some accessible form. I'm under 10k on here so I can't see a darn thing :\

Comment: @Tetsujin There you go. I would like OP to clarify exactly what they're asking, but I suspect it's pronunciation rather than hyphenation, and the answer will be phonemic.

Comment: Is it "every website"? Maybe you meant dictionary? In any case, please include the name and link of at least one of those websites that breaks *photographer* in the way you claimed. I have voted to close because your question does not cite any sources, I don't see why anyone has to look for dictionaries/sites that syllabize it as *pho-tog-ra-phy* is

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you are confused by the fact that because we say 'photo' we should then just tack on 'graphy' without changing the pronunciation of 'photo' - so you would arrive at **'photo** graphy?

As with many combination words this is not actually true, the emphasis and stressed syllable moves. Similarly with many words suffixed by -ography, -onomy, -ology, the stress moves to the first **'o'** of the suffix.
Ge **'og** raphy, gastr **'on** omy, bi **'ol** ogy etc.

This gives us a change from the expected **'photo** graphy to conform to this rule and we get pho **'tog** raphy. Really the 't' could belong to either group, as you can't stress a consonant in the same way, but a native would perceive 'tog' to be the entire emphasised syllable.

Pho **'to** graphy, however, could push the perception back towards our initial misconception of **'photo** graphy, with a longer 'o' and so wouldn't convey the correct pronunciation so well.
Using 'tog' [which is a word all of its own, describing the heat retention of clothing, duvets etc] and has a definite short 'o', as in 'hot'. 'To' alone may be perceived as in 'toe', especially as our root word is pronounced 'toe', which leads us astray again.

Answer (score 6):

If you are asking how dictionaries break this into syllables for the purpose of pronunciation, according to several dictionaries, it's *pho-to-gra-phy* for American English, and your intuition is absolutely correct. In American English, it is only broken into syllables as *pho-tog-ra-phy* for the purpose of hyphenating the word at the end of the line. In British English, some dictionaries syllabalize it for pronunciation as pho-tog-ra-phy. The difference between these is that the o is "short" or "lax" in British English, meaning it must be followed by a consonant and "long" or "tense" in American English, meaning it need not be followed by a consonant.

These two syllabifications, for pronunciation and hyphenation, don't always agree, although they often do, and you shouldn't use the one of these syllabifications for the purpose of purpose of the other.

See [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/photography), that gives the pronunciation (fə-ˈtä-grə-fē) [using its own pronunciation symbols, not IPA].
and [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/photography), that gives the American pronunciation /fəˈtɑː.ɡrə.fi/, but the British pronunciation /fəˈtɒɡ.rə.fi/, with the syllable *tog*, as you were asking about.

Possibly you are asking about how to split the word into syllables so as to hyphenate the word at the end of a line. The rules for hyphenation in English are rather arcane and differ between England and the United States; they usually reflect the pronunciation, but don't always.

[Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385/what-are-the-rules-for-splitting-words-at-the-end-of-a-line?noredirect=1&lq=1) is a question that gives the rules for hyphenating syllables at the end of a line. I assume that the rule which makes the hyphenation fall after **tog** is

- Never break a word after a short vowel in an accented syllable (rap-id but stu-pid).

Hyphenating the word after the "o" would be justified by the rule

- Break words at morpheme boundaries.

The vowel in *tog* is the short vowel /ɒ/ in British English, but is the long vowel /ɑː/ (or sometimes /ɔː/) in American English. However, for purposes of hyphenation, American dictionaries often seem to treat the letter "o" as a short vowel when it's not pronounced /oʊ/. (As I mention above, the rules are arcane.)

Comment: Are you sure your first paragraph is the right way round? Perhaps that version is American; I *pronounce* "photog-" but *hyphenate* as "photo-". Perhaps I'm just weird.

Comment: @Andrew: You're right. The first paragraph is the right way round for American English, but at least two online hyphenation programs give the syllabification pho-to-gra-phy for British English. I assume because they're using the rule *Break words at morpheme boundaries*,

Comment: @AndrewLeach, it's not just you. I'm American (grew up in Georgia, but parents were born in Ohio), and I also would _pronounce_ it as "photog-", but _hyphenate_ it like you're saying.

Answer (score -1):

I think pronunciation is the answer. We say pho **'tog** ra phy. A vertical line, aka a stress mark, precedes the stressed syllable.